# need to sync eclipse in more than one computers

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, synchronize

I have a laptop and a desktop , I use my laptop at office for doing my Java projects, I also want to continue doing my work at home in desktop. So I need to synchronize all my work done in laptop to my desktop, is there any option that can keep my projects synchronized so that I can start my work from where I have stopped.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use a version control system.

Comment: You should use a version-control system anyway; it makes it much easier to recover from errors like deleting the wrong file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git + Github (if your projects are not secretive, otherwise pinpoint each computer as the remote repositry one of another) + Egit from Eclipse.

I use four machines to work with my code and this have been by far the most convinient method of doing things for me, especially if you need someone from the outside to view and edit your coude later on.

Comment: You can also have your upstream repository on an USB flashdrive you carry between computers.